# How to convert video volumes (after dense sampling) with different scales to descriptor?

Tags: computer-vision, anomaly-detection

I read this article ([link](http://cim.mcgill.ca/~javan/index_files/PapersAndPosters/An%20on-line,%20real-time%20learning%20method%20for%20detecting%20anomalies%20in%20videos%20using%20spatio-temporal%20compositions.pdf)) and try to understand algorithm, that presented there.
So, now I understand almost all points from this article, but have question:

How to convert video volumes (after dense sampling) with different scales to descriptor?

As I understand, if I have video with 100 frames with 120*160, then I apply dense scale with different scales(for example `[5*5*5, 10*10*10, 20*20*20]` ), then I will get respectively `[15360, 1920, 240]` cubes. But, after that I need to make descriptors for each of them, and length of descriptors must be the same(in this article length of descriptor is the same as size of cube, so `[125, 1000, 8000]`).

One of the solutions, that I think is create for each pixel cubes in different scales and after that concatenate them in one vector with length 9125. Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've found the answer. 
Around each pixel I must to build cubes each size(so, it will be around 1920000 cubes for each size)